# How do I use an array element as an iterator in julia?

Tags: loops, math, vector, julia, readability

I'm trying to make my Julia code more understandable (to physicists) and thought it would be nice if I could use some sort of vector type iterator. I'm trying to use each element as an iterator. My solution so far is:

```
kcut=2
 = Array{Float64}(undef,3)
Ø = [0, 0, 0]

for [1] in -kcut:kcut, [2] in -kcut:kcut, [3] in -kcut:kcut
    if norm()^2 <= kcut^2 &&  != Ø
        println()
    end
end
println()
```

which almost does what it's supposed to. The only problem is once I've finished the for loop my **M** is redefined to the last configuration it took in the loop, [2,2,2] int this case. This does not seem to be the case when I iterate over a normal variable as below

```
x=1
for x in 1:10
    println(x)
end
println(x)
```

Which tells me x is still equal to 1 after the loop. I would like to have the same behavior if possible. Also is there any way to do this without defining **M** before I use it to iterate?

EDIT: I need **M** to be outputted as an array so I can do some Linear algebra on it.

Comment: Would `for (M₁, M₂, M₃) in (-kcut:kcut) ⊗ (-kcut:kcut) ⊗ (-kcut:kctu)` be "physical" enough? Because then you could define the `\otimes` to be a synonym for `Iterators.product`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following with `StaticArrays` to get "tuples that can do linear algebra":

```
julia> using StaticArrays

julia> ⊗(u, v) = (i ⊗ j for i in u for j in v)
⊗ (generic function with 1 method)

julia> ⊗(x::Number, y::Number) = SVector(x, y)
⊗ (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> ⊗(x::SVector{N}, y::Number) where {N} = SVector(x..., y)
⊗ (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> collect((1:3) ⊗ (10:12) ⊗ (100:101))
18-element Array{SArray{Tuple{3},Int64,1,3},1}:
 [1, 10, 100]
 [1, 10, 101]
 [1, 11, 100]
 [1, 11, 101]
 [1, 12, 100]
 [1, 12, 101]
 [2, 10, 100]
 [2, 10, 101]
 [2, 11, 100]
 [2, 11, 101]
 [2, 12, 100]
 [2, 12, 101]
 [3, 10, 100]
 [3, 10, 101]
 [3, 11, 100]
 [3, 11, 101]
 [3, 12, 100]
 [3, 12, 101]

julia> using LinearAlgebra: norm

julia> for M in (1:3) ⊗ (10:12) ⊗ (100:101)
           println(norm(M))
       end
100.50373127401788
101.49876846543509
100.60815076324582
101.6021653312566
100.72239075796404
101.7152889196113
100.5186549850325
101.51354589413178
100.62305898749054
101.61692772368194
100.73728207570423
101.73003489628813
100.54352291420865
101.5381701627521
100.64790112068906
101.64152694642087
100.7620960480676
101.75460677532
```

But I'm not sure it's worth it.  Ideally, the `\otimes` for `SVector`s and `Number`s would construct a lazy data structure that only creates the appropriately sized `SVector`s when iterated (instead of splatting as here).  I'm just too lazy to write that now.

A better variant (but slightly less mathy syntax) is to overload `⨂(spaces...)` to do everything at once:

```
julia> ⨂(spaces::NTuple{N}) where {N} = (SVector{N}(t) for t in Iterators.product(spaces...))
⨂ (generic function with 1 method)

julia> ⨂(spaces...) = ⨂(spaces)
⨂ (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> collect(⨂(1:3, 10:11))
3×2 Array{SArray{Tuple{2},Int64,1,2},2}:
 [1, 10]  [1, 11]
 [2, 10]  [2, 11]
 [3, 10]  [3, 11]

julia> collect(⨂(1:3, 10:11, 100:101))
3×2×2 Array{SArray{Tuple{3},Int64,1,3},3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 [1, 10, 100]  [1, 11, 100]
 [2, 10, 100]  [2, 11, 100]
 [3, 10, 100]  [3, 11, 100]

[:, :, 2] =
 [1, 10, 101]  [1, 11, 101]
 [2, 10, 101]  [2, 11, 101]
 [3, 10, 101]  [3, 11, 101]
```

This collects to a different shape, although I'd consider that even more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

You can maybe iterate directly on **M**, for example like this:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra: norm
julia> kcut=2;
julia> Ø = [0, 0, 0];

julia> for  in Iterators.product(-kcut:kcut, -kcut:kcut, -kcut:kcut)
           if norm()^2 <= kcut^2 &&  != Ø
               #  is a Tuple now, which should be best in most cases.
               #
               # If you want arrays instead:
                = collect()

               println(, "\t", )
           end
       end
(0, 0, -2)      [0, 0, -2]
(-1, -1, -1)    [-1, -1, -1]
(0, -1, -1)     [0, -1, -1]
(1, -1, -1)     [1, -1, -1]
(-1, 0, -1)     [-1, 0, -1]
(0, 0, -1)      [0, 0, -1]
(1, 0, -1)      [1, 0, -1]
(-1, 1, -1)     [-1, 1, -1]
...

julia> println()
ERROR: UndefVarError:  not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[5]:1
```

This way, **M** is only defined within the scope of the `for` loop.

To understand the behavior of your original code, you have to have a basic understanding of the code transformations ("code lowering") that Julia internally performs. In particular, the `for`  loop is replaced following the rules of the [iteration](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-iteration-1) interface

All in all, a snippet like the following:

```
M = [42]
for M[1] in -k:k
    println(M[1])
end
```

behaves in the same way as:

```
M = [42]
next = iterate(-k:k)
while next !== nothing
    M[1] = i
    println(M[1])
    next = iterate(iter, state)
end
```

Where you see that `M`  has to pre-exist so that `M[1]=i` does not fail, and there is no reason why what happens inside the loop body does not persist after it.

Comment: This is cool. I should clarify though. In the loop I actually will need to do linear algebra on  **M** so it would be nice if it was outputted as an array. Is there any way to that through a similar method?

Comment: Since **M** in this case is always going to have size 3, you're going to be much better off (performancewise) with Tuples of 3 elements.

Comment: Nonetheless, I edited my answer to include the conversion if you need it.

Comment: This is the most "Julian" answer. In particular when the size of `kcut` is large, simply generating the entire `Array` instead of using `Iterators` will lead to an out of memory error.